# Postgresql + gorm complex pagination with groups

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have table with GroupId column, and potentially huge number of rows. Is there a way to get that data paginated by groups? For example, get first 10 groups, then next 10 groups etc?

Table would have this structure (not sorted by default) - sorry for bad formatting, for some reason it did not work, but i think it is visible

| Col1 | Col2 | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data A | foo1 | 1 |
| data B | foo2 | 1 |
| data C | foo3 | 2 |

...

So is there a way to get rows efficiently of fist 10 groups, then next 10 groups etc, with not fixed number of rows per group? Let's say there are millions of rows and groups can be any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really paginated as much as you're just querying for data by a bounded identifier (`GroupId`). If you know your groups IDs and they are sequential, then you could do something like this. This is done using pure Go, you could easily incorporate gorm with this.

[go playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/ZLfRbMDf_Ev)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for _, q := range queries() {
        fmt.Println(q)
    }
}

func queries() (out []string) {
    groups := []int{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}
    for i := 0; i < len(groups); i++ {
        var lower, upper int = 0, 0
        if i != 0 {
            lower = groups[i-1]
        }
        upper = groups[i]
        q := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= %v AND GroupId < %v", lower, upper)
        out = append(out, q)
    }
    return
}
```

A call to `queries` prints out each of the queries that should be run to get all of the results in each group. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 0 AND GroupId < 10
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 10 AND GroupId < 20
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 20 AND GroupId < 30
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 30 AND GroupId < 40
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 40 AND GroupId < 50
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 50 AND GroupId < 60
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 60 AND GroupId < 70
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 70 AND GroupId < 80
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 80 AND GroupId < 90
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupId >= 90 AND GroupId < 100
```

So far, we've made the assumption that you already know exactly what 'group buckets' you want to query. If instead we assume that we know how many sequential groups there are (`n`) and how many groups we want per query (the bucket size `s`), we can easily create a function to give us the buckets we should query on.

[go playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/aU5pwf5_-_L)

```
func groups(n, s int) (out []int) {
    for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
        if i == 0 {
            continue
        }
        if i%s == 0 || i == n {
            out = append(out, i)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: thanks! but is this performant enough in case of huge amount of data?

Comment: This isn’t the piece you need to be worried about for performance. These functions are O(n) time and space, but your database will be the bottleneck as well as how you decide to handle what comes back from the queries. These functions will be virtually unnoticeable I would imagine.

Comment: I was referring to query part, is there a way to optimize that somehow?

Comment: @user3728390 think about it, if your problem requires that you load every row in the table, then there's no way to get around loading every row in the table. There may be some minor optimizations you can perform like ordered SQL indexes, or your application could cache data that doesn't change, or you could make the batches bigger so you reduce the amount of time spent for network latency overhead. Performance optimizations are going to come down to how you design your application. If you have to load an entire table repeatedly, that may be a sign of bad application design.